# Refresh a um div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com problemas em aplicar na minha plataforma o seguinte código Javascript:

```
<script>
    var $scores = $("#refresh");
    setInterval(function() {
        $scores.load("index.php #refresh");
    }, 30000); 
</script>
```

Porque a `<div>` em questão ta num ficheiro aparte e faço `include` dela em todas as páginas ou seja nunca irei saber qual é a página em que o script irá correr e no código em cima tenho que especificar uma página ex: `index.php`

Comment: O que é que não funciona? podes descrever o problema?

Comment: O problema e que como não sei em que pagina vou estar o scricpt nunca chega a correr pq tenho que lhe dizer qual e a pagina actual como pode ver no codigo `load("index.php #refresh");`

Comment: :/ ainda não percebi. Essa string que passas ao .load() deve ser diferente dependendo que em que página está?

Comment: sim onde esta `index.php` deve ser a o nome da pagina ponto a sua extensão

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo de como são os urls das páginas ?

Comment: por exemplo `home.php` , `avisos.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se compreendi bem queres usar nesta string `$scores.load("index.php #refresh")` o nome do ficheiro da página que tens no url.

Por exemplo o url/página `dominio.com/home.php` deve fazer com que o `.load()` vá buscar `"home.php #refresh"`.

Para fazeres isso podes usar uma expressão regular, filtrando esse nome:

```
var nome = window.location.href.match(/\/(\w+)\.php/);
if (nome) nome = nome[0];
```

e depois usar esse nome no `.load()` assim:

```
var nome = window.location.href.match(/\/(\w+)\.php/);
if (nome) nome = nome[0];
var $scores = $("#refresh");
setInterval(function() {
    $scores.load(nome + " #refresh");
}, 30000);
```

Podes ver a regex [aqui (link)](https://regex101.com/r/dJ3fM8/1), o que ela procura é por uma barra `\/` seguida de 1 ou mais letras capturando-as `(\w+)`, e que seja seguido de `.php`.

Testa o código e diz se funciona como queres.

Comment: Funciona sim senhor obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira fácil é a de atribuir uma variável no arquivo principal (antes da inclue), em seguida, fazer referência a essa variável no arquivo incluído.

**Parent File:**

```
$myvar_not_replicated = __FILE__; // Make sure nothing else is going to overwrite
include 'other_file.php';
```

**Included File:**

```
if (isset($myvar_not_replicated)) echo "{$myvar_not_replicated} included me";
else echo "Unknown file included me";
```